# How do I create a javascript bookmarklet with a delay/timeout inside?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make a javascript bookmarklet in Chrome to load a webpage, wait 5 seconds, then run a function on that page named close() which closes an ad. I've tried the following but I can't get it to work:

```
javascript:(function(){window.location.href="http://www.example.com",setTimeout(function(){close()},5000)})();
```

It seems that setTimeout is the proper way to pause before running code but I can't seem to get the syntax right I guess. I tried replacing "close()" with another page redirect but it never gets called. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that the context for the code will be the current window.

As soon as you assign `window.location.href="http://www.example.com"` a new page will load with a new window instance and any code after that will be gone along with the previous window instance

Comment: It actually does load in the same tab. window.open() seems to do what you describe though. Thanks for taking a look, any other ideas?

Comment: @djh the point is `close()` will never execute in the new context, whether you use `href=` or `open()` the problem is the same.

Comment: I realize it opens in same tab... but javascript isn't persistent and all the script from previous window is gone. What you are basically trying to do is run some code on one page...and when a new page loads run some more code.... can't do that

Comment: Ah damn :( Ok thanks charlietfl and @Matt. Is there some other way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: @djh I think it's safe to say bookmarklets cannot do this sort of persistence. I would suggest looking at something like Chrome extensions. Like: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

Comment: OK thanks I'll read up. Thank you both for the helpful advice!

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
javascript:(() => {const sleep = ms => new Promise(y => setTimeout(y,ms));var win = window.open("https://example.com");sleep(5000).then(() => win.close())})();
```

Comment: This actually works but opens another tab, it doesn't make the current tab to navigate to the target page. and it will also work without creating the promise...